# Windows 8 app scaling

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I don't get it why when I run sample Windows 8.1 app on 1280 x 800 device (HP Stream 7 Signature Edition) it reports the following values when run full screen in tablet mode:

- width: 1542.16870117188
- height: 963.855407714844
- scale factor: Scale100Percent

and different ones when the tablet mode is disabled:

- width: 1802.816894531
- height: 1126.76062011719
- scale factor: Scale100Percent.

The following code was used to display the values:

```
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
WidthView.Text = string.Format("Width: {0}", Window.Current.Bounds.Width);
HeightView.Text = string.Format("Height: {0}", Window.Current.Bounds.Height);
ScaleFactorView.Text = String.Format("Scale factor: {0}", displayInformation.ResolutionScale);
```

I'm surprised that:

- I see different values depending on the tablet mode state (both runs were full screen)
- the scale factor multiplied by reported width / height doesn't equal to the expected dimensions 1280 x 800
- the scale factor is wrongly reported or looks like being less than 1.0 (due to the observation above). I was expecting to see always reported width / height less than or equal to 1280 x 800 for this device.

I must be missing something.

Comment: I assume you are actually running on Windows 10 since you mention "Tablet Mode"? What is the scale that the shell is running at?

Comment: `ResolutionScale` is not capable of reporting all scales. It rounds to the nearest scale factor available in the `ResolutionScale` enumeration (100% in this case). Use `RawPixelToViewPixel` to get the true scale factor, fractions and all.

Comment: Yes it is Windows 10. I'm not sure if I understand "What is the scale that the shell is running at?".

Comment: RawPixelsPerViewPixel reports fine. It is 1.25 and the width, height reported is 1024 x 640 which matches perfectly 1280 x 800.

Comment: But I had to convert the app to `Windows 10 app`. I understand the limitations of `ResolutionScale` enumerations but I'm still surprised that also width / height was affected when the app was built for `Windows 8`.

Comment: And when the app was built for `Windows 10` the same values were reported in both modes: tablet and normal.